# Как работает рекурсивный DNS сервер с сокетами?

Tags: c, сокет, dns

Суть такая, пишу сервер на Си, который по стандартному #53 порту слушает на сокете udp запросы. Принамаю их, обрабатываю, отправляю ответ, все гуд.
Но мне нужно рекурсивно отсылать этот запрос на другой сервер, чтоб узнать адрес, так вот получается, что сокет для рекурсивного запроса один в один совпадает с сокетом для прослушки и ответы со следующего сервера прилетают на мой слушающий сокет как новый запрос, в результате каша.
Как правильно оформимть этот момент, подскажите плиз? Уже несколько дней на одном месте...
Адрес след сервера чтоб можно было менять.

Comment: наверно, содержимое пакетов разное и можно определить, это запрос или это ответ. С другой стороны, когда Вы оправили пакет, наверно адрес сервера то знаете, вот по нему можно и определить

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но все дело в том, что как только мне пришел запрос, я делаю fork() и уже в дочернем обрабатываю его, а если родительский приемет его вместо дочернего, то я его уже не найду. Создаю дочерний процесс для одновременной обработки большого кол-ва запросов.

Comment: создайте себе ещё один сокет и через него отправляйте запросы.

Comment: Создал, но т.к. это udp там то и настроить толком нечего, только порт и тот совпадает, в результате два одинаковых сокета.

Comment: дык, отправляй запросы с другого порта...

Comment: Ооо, точно, спасибо) я натупил, думал ставлю dst port, а ставил src)

Comment: есть такая штука bind

Comment: Всем спасибо!!)

Comment: а если не bind'ить, то система автомагическим образом присвоит сободный порт...